# Azure Resource Manager - optimistic concurrency

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, optimistic-concurrency

I am using ARM (Rest API) to download resources and upload tags. Is there a way to use optimistic concurrency (etags maybe ?) to catch concurrency issues?

Comment: Which resource do you want to download? If using Azure storage, [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/) could helps.

Comment: Generally everything, and I use ARM Rest API to do that.